# Can't get Topics endpoint in Cognitive Services

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, text-analysis, text-analytics-api

I was trying to run a sample app that gets the topics endpoint for microsoft cognitive services Text Analytics API but the function return 400 HTTP error.

Here is the code:

```
static async Task<string> CallTopicEndpoint(HttpClient client, string uri, byte[] byteData)
{
    using (var content = new ByteArrayContent(byteData))
    {
        content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
        var response = await client.PostAsync(uri, content);
        // Return URL containing OperationID to poll from.
        return response.Headers.GetValues("Operation-Location").First();
    }
}
```

Full sample is in here:
https://text-analytics-demo.azurewebsites.net/Home/SampleCode

Any help is appreciate it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The topic detection capability was deprecated a while back. If you still need topic detection capabilities, you may want to look into this Topic Detection [Azure ML Experiment](https://gallery.cortanaintelligence.com/Experiment/Topic-Detection).

Luis Cabrera | Text Analytics Program Manager | Cloud AI Platform, Microsoft